# Landscape figures and captions

Tags: captions, figures, word-2016

I'm trying to add a caption to a landscape figure, displaying in a portrait document (see img)[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mmkT.png). The caption needs to display in landscape (i.e. can be viewed with the image, when the page is turned 90 deg.). It also needs to stay consistent with other figure captions and display in the table of figures in the menu.

Is this possible in word 2016?

Comment: You didn't read the bold text next to the question box that says: **Is your question about programming?**

Answer (score -1):

Despite suggestions elsewhere on the web, this has an easy solve. You can put a caption in a text box, that will follow numbering throughout the rest of the document and appear within the table of contents. Hope this helps someone in future.